# Is Guava cache's RemovalListener synchronized?

Tags: java, guava

I am wondering if the `RemovalListener` of a Guava cache is synchronized on the key of the removed entry. As far as I understand it, the Guava cache is built on top of a `SynchronizedHashMap` and an entry will not be loaded twice if I make two calls to the cache's `get` method on the same key since the calls synchronize on the same sequence of the `SynchronizedHashMap`. Now I am wondering if a user can call `get` while a `RemovalListener` is still running its `onRemoval(RemovalNotification)` method on a different thread.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the source code not freely available?

Comment: It is, but I thought I might just ask. If nobody knows the answer, I will dig through the source myself tomorrow and answer my own question when I am back at the office tomorrow. But if somebody knows, this would safe me time of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Guava cache is more like a `ConcurrentHashMap`, though it's not built "on top of" a CHM; it involves a rewrite of the whole thing.

That said, the answer to your question is that if an entry is being processed by a `RemovalListener`, it is no longer in the cache, and a `get` query will be treated just as if the entry was never in the cache: by loading the value for that key from scratch.

Comment: It is indeed not synchronized, I checked the source code today. Thank you for your answer!